# HTML5 local database - is there a solution that will work in all browsers?

Tags: html, indexeddb, web-sql

Trying to write a website/webapp , should work both on desktop and mobile.
I will need a client side database support, but could not find a solution that would work both for popular browsers (FF/IE) and also on iOS.

It states everywhere that I should either go for IndexedDB or Web SQL - but I want full support and I don't want to use two databases depending on the client machine.

I know this question might be duplicated, but I could not find an answer with a reliable substitute for the *IndexedDB* - *Web SQL* solutions.

Any advice ?

The database should store a lot of textual data and should also textual search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with IndexedDB way with using [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) (a polyfill for WebSQL, it works well on iOS devices ) as well. IndexedDB has a decent support now in both desktop and mobile browsers.
For storage quota, notice that IOS devices allows maximum of 50 MB storage, whereas on other browsers there is no hard limit.

IndexedDB doesn't have any free text search API. You need to build it on your own, or look at this library [YDN-DB](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home). This may prove helpful for you !!